# Запрос на скачивания файла с сервера

Tags: php

Какой запрос может быть использован и с какими парамертами чтобы скачать файл `README.md` с веб-сервера?

Веб-сервер Apache

В конфигаруционном файле Apache присуцствуют следующии настройки:

```
<Files README.md>
deny from all
</Files>
```

Comment: Вы напрямую запретили всем доступ к файлу и хотите его скачать после этого? О_о

Comment: @Visman Может быть есть способ) Представим что апач сломался или мы его как-то сломали или может быть как-то еще

Comment: Способ-то есть, но зачем такие извращения?

Comment: @Visman Чтобы самого не взломали )

Comment: Получается я прав и это не надёжная защита?

Comment: Может Ddos необходимо произвести перегрузить апач? А?